# Undefined while passing value of patientId

Tags: reactjs

How would I go about passing the value of patientId down since all I get now is undefined.

```
const patientId = "1";
<Log messages={messages} patientId={patientId}/>
```

other class

```
export default function Log({ messages },{patientId
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(patientId); 
  }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while getting the props in the function you made a mistake. this is the correct way. Try this :

```
export default function Log({ messages, patientId}) {
  useEffect(() => {
  console.log(patientId); 
   }, [])
}
```